# Cannot get class name from node after locating it in playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I have an SVG object like that:

```html
<svg class="class-a color-green marker" .../>
```

In Playwright I want to get an exact list of classes of this element. I use the following code to locate it:

```py
page.locator(".status-marker").first
```

The node is located properly, but when I call `evaluate("node => node.className")` on it, I get an empty dict, like the locator stripped all information about classes at all.

In general, it doesn't matter how I get the handle of this element, I always get an empty dict on `evaluate("node => node.className")`.

Calling `page.locator(".status-marker").first.is_visible()` returns `True`, so the object exists.

Also if I run `page.locator(".status-marker").first.evaluate("node => node.outerHTML")` I'll get the full HTML of that node, that does have the class name included. I could parse that, but it would be pretty clunky solution.

I found out that I could use `expect(locator).to_have_class()`, but If the node has more than one class I need to put all of them for it to pass, when I care only on one of them (the other classes are dynamically generated, so I can't even know about them during tests).

Edit:

Here's some additional sample:

```py
assert page.locator(".marker").first.evaluate("node => node.className") == {}
expect(page.locator(".marker").first).to_have_class("text-green-1")
```

The first assert passes - the `evaluate("node => node.className")` returns an empty dict. The `expect()` fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: Locator expected to have class 'text-green-1'
E       Actual value: inline pr-2 text-green-1 marker svelte-fa s-z-WEjw8Gh1FG
```

I've found a way to reproduce it (it happens to me in font awesome plugin for svelte):

```py
def test_svelte_fa(page):
    page.goto("https://cweili.github.io/svelte-fa/")

    item = page.locator(".svelte-fa").first
    assert item.is_visible()
    assert "svelte-fa" in item.evaluate("node => node.className")
```

Comment: I navigated the URL of this question and `page.locator('#question > div.post-layout > div.votecell.post-layout--left > div > div.js-vote-count.flex--item.d-flex.fd-column.ai-center.fc-black-500.fs-title').first.evaluate("node => node.className")` worked as expected.

Comment: @hardkoded - I've updated the question with an example on another public website where I managed to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `className` of an `SVG` is an `SVGAnimatedString` object. Which is not serializable.
If you do `JSON.stringify($('.svelte-fa').className)` on the browser, you will see that the value is `{}`.
Values returned by the `evaluate` function needs to be serializable.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I managed to get the class value with `node.className.baseVal`.